# Wordpress unwanted echo

Tags: wordpress, function, echo

```
$name = single_tag_title();
```

Can anybody tell me why I always get in an issue like this in wordpress?

**Why does this echo instead of assigning that value to $name?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

seems like you need to set the display argument to false.

something like  `$name = single_tag_title('', false);`

[see the codex for deets](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_tag_title)